# Linked servers prevent a T-SQL query from using parallel execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I directly join a local table with a remote table by using linked server [LinkedServerA], the actual execution plan is not parallel.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM LinkedServerA.DatabaseA.dbo.ProductA A
INNER JOIN DatabaseB.dbo.ProductB B ON A.ProductID = B.ProductID
OPTION (RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8649) --Force the query run in parallelism
```

But if I get data from the remote table and insert data into a local temporary table #TmpProductA, the execution plan is parallel.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM #TmpProductA A
INNER JOIN DatabaseB.dbo.ProductB B ON A.ProductID = B.ProductID
OPTION (RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8649) --Force the query run in parallelism
```

My question is that why using linked server prevent query from parallelism? I searched on the internet but there are not any official documents explain this behavior clearly ? Btw, I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3.

Comment: Although not referencing parallelism directly, this article does contain lots of info on why plans change when using linked servers: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-query-vs-linked-server-leon-gordon

Comment: Also this, parallelism via linked server: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1700903-391-1.aspx